# Morris js chart loads twice

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I'm using Morris js to draw basic line chart. Here is my code:

```
function getChart(range) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "page.php?doChart=1&range=" + range,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(json) {
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'chart',
            data: json.data,
            xkey: 'month',
            ykeys: json.xkey,
            labels: json.label,
            parseTime: false
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getChart('all');
    $("#timeRange").on('click', function() {
        getChart($(this).data('value'))
    });
});
```

The above code works just fine on page load, the problem is when I try to load chart for different period, using on click event. Original container id #chart is being replaced, but for some reason the same instances of chart is being created just below #chart div.

Comment: what does the "getStats"  function do? Might be worth sharing that too.

Comment: @ADyson. Sorry , I have fixed the typo, its the same function being called after click event.

Comment: Why not just remove the old chart and then insert a new one?

Comment: @Adjit I was thinking about that, but it has to be a better cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function getChart(range) {
  $("#chart").empty();
  $.ajax({
... etc
```

Every time you run the Morris.Line function, it inserts an `<svg>` element into your chosen element ("chart" in your case). It doesn't overwrite the previous one, it adds an extra one. So you need to clear the old chart out first.

See this demo to demonstrate the duplication issue:
http://jsbin.com/yelonizoce/1/edit?html,js,output

And this one to demonstrate the use of `.empty();` 
http://jsbin.com/xinegovoqo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Before create new chart, old chart should be destroyed. For this use Jquery `.empty()` function.

```
$('#chartID').empty();
```

more information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141815/20680598).